# Having a subview inside of another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, scenekit

My SCNView is full screen, but I would like to add a view in the bottom right corner like a minimap of a game. I have the code working separately in each of the views, but I have no idea how to view both of them at the same time.

If possible, I would also like it so that if the smaller view is touched, the position of the two views are swapped (the main view becomes the mini-view, and the mini-view becomes the main view) -- which could be repeated as needed to swap them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCNView is a subclass of UIView so you can treat it like a regular view. There are too many different ways to handle this to cover them all. But for example, use [addSubview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview) to add one to the other. You could for example also use a popover view in the first scene, and add the minimap sceneview to the popover.

To swap them around you can use one master view (like the one of your main view controller) and then add the first sceneview, and to that sceneview add the mini map. When you tap the mini map you can simply remove them from their parents and add them again in the desired hierarchy. Another option would be to add both sceneviews to a master view and resize them and then use sendSubviewToBack on the sceneview that was the minimap.